# Sum of multiplicities of a plane curve

Tags: algebraic-curves

Suppose $f$ is a bivariate polynomial that defines an irreducible plane curve of degree $d$ over some algebraically closed field $k$. We know that by Bézout's that summing over points on the curve: 
\begin{align*}
\sum_P m_P(f)(m_P(f)-1) \leq d(d-1).
\end{align*}

Is there any bound on $\sum_P m_P(f)$? Just like for the univariate polynomial that $\sum_P m_P(f) = d$.

I’m interested in bounding the sum of multiplicities of singular points on an irreducible curve over the finite field. Any literature recommendation along that direction is also appreciated.

Comment: There's a lot of points with $m_P(f)=1$.

Comment: I’m not quite sure what you are hinting to. The number of singular points of an plane curve can certainly be bounded by $O(d^2)$. Is this what you are referring to?